I am getting the error "platformUtilityBarApi.getUtilityInfo is not a function" when trying to get info about the wrapping UtilityBar
I am getting this error in Salesforce when my LWC component is inside the UtilityBar.

According to the documentation there are 2 functions and the second one is dedicated to directly return for the instance specified by it's ID:

getAllUtilityInfo()
Returns a promise that resolves to an array of utilityInfo objects if successful. The promise is rejected on error.
getUtilityInfo(utilityId)
utilityId (string): ID of the utility for which to get info.
Returns a promise that resolves to a utilityInfo object if successful. The promise is rejected on error.

Source documentation.

The real method to import from 'lightning/platformUtilityBarApi' is getInfo(utilityId).
To avoid any future change of the name to the documented one, I am going to import both methods:
import {EnclosingUtilityId, getInfo, getUtilityInfo, // main
open, minimize, updatePanel, updateUtility // additional
} from 'lightning/platformUtilityBarApi';

and then use the one that actually exists:
const infoFunction = getInfo || getUtilityInfo;
infoFunction(this.utilityId).then((utilityInfo)=>{
    this.utilityLabel = utilityInfo.label;
});

